# What is the dual space of $L^2([0,1],[0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $L^2([0,1],[0,1])$ contains all Lebesgue square-integrable functions mapping from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. Does the dual sapce be represesnted by all functions in $L^2([0,1],[0,1])$ or all functions in $L^2([0,1],R)$?

Comment: You need a definition of "dual space" for something that is not a vector space.

Comment: So $L^2([0,1],[0,1])$ is not a vector space, for it is not closed under addition?

Comment: ... and not closed under scalar multiple.

Comment: How about I treat it as a subspace of $L^2([0,1],R)$? It seems that it is not a subspace neither.